# Unlink of file 'debug.log' failed. Should I try again?

Tags: git

Eu fazia várias git stash na minha branch normalmente.
Mas agora quando eu passo o comando:
`git stash save "teste"`

**ele responde:**

Saved working directory and index state On dev: teste
Unlink of file 'debug.log' failed.

Should I try again? (y/n) y

Unlink of file 'debug.log' failed.

Should I try again? (y/n) y

Unlink of file 'debug.log' failed.

Should I try again? (y/n) y

Unlink of file 'debug.log' failed.

Should I try again? (y/n) y

Enfim não consigo mas usar o stash, se eu der não (y/n)n ele não funciona em nada.

Comment: Já checou a permissão da pasta de arquivos? Está usando linux?

Comment: estou usando windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que algum outro programa esteja usando o arquivo, aí não é possível mover esse arquivo para dentro ou fora do diretório de trabalho.

Tenta fechar qualquer programa ou processo que possa estar usando o arquivo. Abre o gerenciador de tarefas do windows(CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) e encerrar qualquer processo que posa estar usando o arquivo, tipo eclipse, etc..

Você pode usar o programa [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) para encontrar qual processo està usando o arquivo.